# How can I tell svn to ignore certain files anywhere?

Tags: svn

How do I tell svn that every time, in any directory of any project, it encounters `foo` and `bar` it has to completely ignore them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out ~/.subversion/config's global-ignore option:

```
### Set global-ignores to a set of whitespace-delimited globs
### which Subversion will ignore in its 'status' output.
# global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la #*# .*.rej *.rej .*~ *~ .#* .DS_Store
```

Answer (score 0):

The `global-ignore` option can also be entered in [Subversion's system-wide configuration file](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.layout) to have it apply to all users and all repositories.

As an example, I added the following to `/etc/subversion/config` on my Linux/CentOS system:

```
[miscellany]
global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a *.pyc *.pyo *.rej *~ #*# .#* .*.swp .DS_Store ._*
```

I based this configuration on my user's default `~/.subversion/config` value for the `global-ignores` option, initially commented out by Subversion.

Now all those name patterns will be ignored for all users.